# Return address from marker

Tags: reverse, geocode

I'm very new to reverse geocoding. I have managed to place a dragable marker on a map which when dropped returns the Lat/Long to text boxes on a form using the code below:

```
div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 467px"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps? 
file=api&v=2&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
<!--
if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) 
{
// create map and add controls
var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());        
map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
map.enableScrollWheelZoom();
//map.enableGoogleBar();

// set centre point of map
var centrePoint = new GLatLng('53.767789993998804', '-2.7046966552734375');
map.setCenter(centrePoint, 10); 

// add a draggable marker
var marker = new GMarker(centrePoint, {draggable: true});
map.addOverlay(marker);

// add a drag listener to the map
GEvent.addListener(marker, "dragend", function() {
var point = marker.getPoint();
map.panTo(point);
document.getElementById("latitude").value = point.lat().toFixed(5);
document.getElementById("longitude").value = point.lng().toFixed(5);

});
}

</script>
```

This works fine but I would also like to capture the street name to a text box but am lost. I know I can't do it using 'point' and have to define a function but am completely lost and google searches have turned up nothing of use to someone starting out like me.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I reckon the answer is here:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#ReverseGeocoding

But you'll need to upgrade to version 3 of Google Maps API.